# Cannot destructure property 'notes' of 'context' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to use context with hooks to manage Notes in my react app. I'm getting the error **Cannot destructure property 'notes' of 'context' as it is undefined.**

the console error is

---

```
**Notes.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 
'notes' 
of 'context' as it is undefined.**
at Notes (Notes.js:10:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
Notes @ Notes.js:10
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533



**Notes.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'notes' 
of 'context' as it is undefined.**
at Notes (Notes.js:10:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
Notes @ Notes.js:10
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the             
<Notes> component:

at Notes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:769:68)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75599:5)
at RenderErrorBoundary 
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75550:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76064:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76002:15)
at RouterProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75849:5)
at App

**React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using 
the error boundary you provided, RenderErrorBoundary.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
hooks.tsx:550 React Router caught the following error during render 
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'notes' of 'context' as it is 
undefined.**
at Notes (Notes.js:10:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
```

---

this is the code of NoteContext.js

```
import React,{createContext} from 'react'

export const NoteContext = createContext()
```

this is the code of NoteState.js

```
import { NoteContext } from "./noteContext";
import { useState } from "react";

import React from 'react'
import Notes from "../../components/Notes";

export default function NoteState() {
    const notesInitial = [
    {
      "_id": "64073219511b4f062e4291d1",
      "user": "63fe0f8bbea2272fc98d6e2e",
      "title": "Fitness",
      "description": "Get ready and go for exercises at 1pm",
      "tag": "Personal, Fitness",
      "Date": "2023-03-07T12:46:17.031Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "6407323a511b4f062e4291d3",
      "user": "63fe0f8bbea2272fc98d6e2e",
      "title": "Hello MY boy",
      "description": "its Testing time baby",
      "tag": "Fitness",
      "Date": "2023-03-07T12:46:50.803Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]

  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(notesInitial)
    
  return (
    <div>
        <NoteContext.Provider value={{notes, setNotes}}>
            <Notes/>
        </NoteContext.Provider>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is the code of Notes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { NoteContext } from '../context/notes/NoteContext';



export default function Notes() {
 const context = useContext(NoteContext)
 const {notes, setNotes} = context


  return (
    <>
 
    <h1 className='yournotes'>Your Notes</h1>
    <div className='savednote-container'>
      {notes.map((note)=>{
        return note.title;
      }
      )}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have tried so much times but getting errors everytime Please someone Help me

Comment: This looks OK at first sight. Could you post anything else that you might have, i.e. the stacktrace, other errors that might appear in the console?

Comment: sure the console is showing that  The above error occurred in the <Notes> component: at Notes.js:10:1

Comment: Could you paste the full error log into your question?

Comment: @Chaoz I have pasted the full error log into your question please have a look

Comment: I think you are using Notes component somewhere else as well, outside of NoteState

Comment: I was using it in my SavedNote Component and now I have removed it but, the problem is still there

Comment: The error is telling that `context` in `Notes.js` is undefined. This is an indication that somewhere in your codebase you are using the `Notes` component without it being wrapped by `NoteContext`

Comment: @myselfprince Simplest way to find out: in NoteState, delete the `<Notes/>` line. Also delete/rename the Notes.js file altogether (just don't lose it, save it somewhere). Then try to build - your bundler should tell you where else Notes is imported (as it fails, due to the file no longer being there).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is your issue:

In your `Notes.js` you are importing your context like so

```
import { NoteContext } from '../context/notes/NoteContext';
```

But in your `NoteState.js` you are importing your context like this

```
import { NoteContext } from "./noteContext";
```

check your import of the context is correct.

Hope that helps

Comment: I had corrected it earlier but didn't worked

Comment: Can you post your project structure, I copied the code you posted and changed the imports and it worked.